# ¿Cómo pintar una columna especifica de un JTable?

Tags: java, eclipse

He estado intentando pintar una columna especifica de un jtable, este es el código que he estado utilizando pero me pinta todas las filas y no la columna en especifica:

```
public class TableCellRender_ControlDocumentos extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
    private int columna ;

    public TableCellRender_ControlDocumentos(int Colpatron)
    {
        this.columna = Colpatron;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent (JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row, int column)
    {      
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected, focused, row, column);

        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel();

        if(columna == 4){
            if(selected)
                etiqueta.setBackground (Color.CYAN);
            else
                etiqueta.setBackground (Color.YELLOW);
        }

        if (value instanceof String){
            etiqueta.setOpaque(true);
            etiqueta.setText((String)value);
        }

        return etiqueta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intente reiniciar el color por defecto de su `JTable` , es decir si no cumple la condición

`if(columna == 4)` el background sea el que tiene por defecto el JTable.

```
if(columna == 4){
        if(selected)
            etiqueta.setBackground (Color.CYAN);
        else
            etiqueta.setBackground (Color.YELLOW);
 }
 else
       etiqueta.setBackground (table.getBackground());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JTabla tabla = new JTabla(element, cabecer);

tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new RenderColorTabla());
```

Creas una clase llamada, por ejemplo, `class RenderColorTabla();`, el cual extiende del `DefaultTableCellRenderer()`.

Dentro de ello pones:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

Con esto, ya tienes todo hecho, solo pones qué columna quieres pintar y listo.

Comment: ¿Dónde defines la columna específica a pintar?